# How to avoid the first-line automatic selection after inserting a new row to the store of a grid

Tags: extjs4

I am using extjs4 to create a gird which can be editable by the "Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing" plugin.
When the user click the "Add" button. It will add a new row to the store for user input. But after the insertion, first row of the grid will be selected automatically. So the cell editor lose the focus everytime.

Related code below:

```
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing');

// part options for grid
selType: 'cellmodel',
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', { checkOnly: true }),
plugins: [cellEditing],

// Add new record
var r = Ext.ModelManager.create({
    id: '',
    name: '',
    label: '',
    description: ''
}, 'Privilege');

pstore.insert(0, r);

cellEditing.startEditByPosition({
    row: 0,
    column: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i try, won't lose focus of input text.
but my code is

```
var r = Ext.create('PlcModel', {
    //eqNo:Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer'),
    slavePos:'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff',
    eqdesc: 'Mostly Shady',
    eqmanu: 'TL-PA201',
    onlineSt: false,signal:0,
    bandwidLimit:512,
    hardwareversion:'V.93.344.0',
    enabled:false,vlanid:105
});
var curStore=Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('PLCTeams');
var len= curStore.count();
curStore.insert(len+1, r);
cellEditing.startEditByPosition({row: len, column: 1});
```

CheckboxModel choose but focus input also exist, you can input
pls not email me, since my login info input wrong for secret
my extjs4 version is 4.0.7

Comment: CheckboxModel causes this problem. I must move on for project, so I had deleted the definition of "selModel".

Thanks for ur help, though.